# Multiple references order in LaTeX

Tags: natbib

I'm writing a paper using the `informs3.cls` class and `natbib` in LaTeX. I need to have some multiple references.

I wonder if there is any general rule for sorting the references within the same `\cite`. Should it be by year or author names ?

Comment: As it stands this seems very vague: what have you tried? Do you mean sorting for input or output?

Comment: What I mean, is that when writing a `\cite` with multiple authors, how we sort them for the output of course. example: should it be `(see, a** 2009, b**2005, c**2010)` or `(see, b**2005, a** 2009, c**2010)`. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Please create a minimal working example so we can see how your input is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t think there is any *general rule*, this is up to you as an author (if there are no rules imposed by the journal you are submitting to).
Usually, the references are printed in the order they appear in `\cite{...}`. 
Natbib, however, offers options to customize this behaviour: `sort` turns [2,3,1] into [1,2,3] and `sort&compress` turns it into [1-3].